# How to create two different domain name using single apache server

Tags: apache2

I am using ubundu OS My senior people assigned a work for create two different web domain name using single apache.
Example :
 first domain name :www.myassignment.com
 Second domain name :www.mymentortask.com

When I am run the two domain it should work on my browser.
How is this possible and please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use "virtual hosts", which are very well documented here : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/

Comment: Thanks Olivier Very use full to your link